# Validate form before move to next page

Tags: javascript, php

I have coded my own validation form. Is there anyway i can prevent page from submit to php (action="process.php" Method="POST") if form is not validated. I have been thinking all day. I have tried with ajax and json. When all fields validated the page never moves an inch or redirect.
Please i prefer my solution in pure javascript. I don't like the frameworks, jquery and stuff. https://codeshare.io/zy91Q7

```
      function validateForm() {
  
  firname();
  lasname();
  addr();
  citnma(),
  zipx();
  checkEmail();
  phnc();

}
```

Comment: Well what you may have not thought of is a *separate* function that validates the form and returns an array of "errors". When this array is empty, submit form, but when not empty display errors and dont submit the form.

Comment: Wow, u got a point boss. can u make small illustration so i can look through?

Comment: I thought i just did "boss" your needed solution.

Comment: i mean like small coding , or site with example or youtube video

Comment: Alright I will give example of the concept. Look for below. This will be a pure javascript solution and is meant to be as an example. You'll have to have to modify to your requirements. Accept it as an answer if it helps.

Comment: But first I need to see what your `firname()` code looks like? You could have just sneaked peeked some code from another student? If it were your code you would have been "proud" to show it, but you didnt for some reason. Seems like you copied/pasted from somewhere and have *no idea* what you are doing.

Comment: oh yh copied and made changes, my changes were more anyway , i just

Comment: Sorry i didnt see your messages

Comment: i wish i could post my codes here but it isnt working .... says 184 long

Comment: Icuzua i wanted to help you. But I realized you just have zero code attempt and its not that you lied, I stand corrected on that. You just showed code that has zero code attempt on the quasi-functions you call which also have zero code attempt. That is you delegated the code problem on functions that simply do not exist yet, since you havent coded them: net sum: zero code attempt

Comment: https://codeshare.io/zy91Q7

Comment: i coded it myself, i just took the style by creating function for everything and calling them in , thats all.

Comment: you can check my code

Comment: I checked that helps. Next time include the link on check on question. But anyway, no disrespect to you as a person, I'm just checking. Solution below. You will have to modify it of course to how you like to work with javascript.

Comment: ok, i'm adding the codes for the function i called.

Comment: you can refresh link and see the other codes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution is just plain js and html. It will need adjustments on validation requirements. It is *only* an idea to handle multiple form elements for validation before submitting.

**Here is the "raw" example which can be run from any browser.**

I will follow up with an example that can be run from here Stack Overflow.

Note that in this SOLUTION the error won't refresh to blank of any input change after the error occurred. You can add this logic in if you like.

I included code comments to explain as it goes along in the code.

RAW CODE TO PASTE TO YOUR EDITOR TEST:

```
<html>
<body>
<!-- give all your input, select, and textarea fields IDs so they can be referenced via javascript -->
<!-- You can still give the "name" attributes if they are to be submitted. -->

<!-- give the form an ID. Remove any explicity "submit" button -->

<!-- Cant real form line here to test -->
<!--form id="theForm" action="" method="" -->

<form id="theForm"> <!-- for testing here on SO -->
    A <input type id="a" name="a"><br/>
    B <input type id="b" name="b"><br/>
    <div id="form_error_message"></div>
    
</form>

<!-- Use type button on button ( and don't name oncick script submit(), important ) -->

<button type="button" onclick="validateFormOrSubmit()">Submit</button>

<script>
function errorsFormFrontEnd() {
    // returns an array of unacceptable input
    // Change these conditionals based on needs of valid form
    
    let errors = [];
    
    // TODO: trim .value to rid white space, not done in this example
    
    if ( document.getElementById("a").value == "") errors.push("a");
    if ( document.getElementById("b").value == "") errors.push("b");
    
    // it would have been easier (typing wise) to loop through form elements above,
    // but I didn't because this an example of the concept.
    
    return errors;
    
}
</script>

<!-- Start new script tags per function so broke code in one doesn't break the other, useful for debugging -->

<script>

function validateFormOrSubmit() {
    
    
    let errors = errorsFormFrontEnd();
    
    if (errors.length == 0) {
        
        // Uncomment next line to do the real submit form to server
        
        // document.getElementById("theForm").submit();
        
        // Next line not needed if you handle it elsewhere
        
        document.getElementById("form_error_message").innerHTML = "All fields meet requirements.";
        
    }
    else {
        
        // errors exist in form, hence length != 0
        
        // Show some kinda form error.
        // Be more specific on these messages with separate spans above each element, idea?.
        // That is, loop over the errors array with explicit if conditions.
        
        // Alteratively make so errors array contains plain language and display that in div.
        
        // For this example "form_error_message" will contain literal text no matter which error occurs.
        
        document.getElementById("form_error_message").innerHTML = "All fields are required.";
            
        // Notice we don't submit the form in this else block.
        // We need validation to submit the form when this function runs next time.
        
    }
        
    
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**For here on SO to test run this solution:**

```js
function errorsFormFrontEnd() {
    // returns an array of unacceptable input
    // Change these conditionals based on needs of valid form
    
    let errors = [];
    
    // TODO: trim .value to rid white space, not done in this example
    
    if ( document.getElementById("a").value == "") errors.push("a");
    if ( document.getElementById("b").value == "") errors.push("b");
    
    // it would have been easier (typing wise) to loop through form elements above,
    // but I didn't because this an example of the concept.
    
    return errors;
    
}

function validateFormOrSubmit() {
    // validates the form, if not valid reports errors, if valid submits to server
    
    let errors = errorsFormFrontEnd();
    
    if (errors.length == 0) {
        
        // Uncomment next line to do the real submit form to server
        
        // document.getElementById("theForm").submit();
        
        // Next line not needed if you handle it elsewhere
        
        document.getElementById("form_error_message").innerHTML = "All fields meet requirements.";
        
    }
    else {
        
        // errors exist in form, hence length != 0
        
        // Show some kinda form error.
        // Be more specific on these messages with separate spans above each element, idea?.
        // That is, loop over the errors array with explicit if conditions.
        
        // Alteratively make so errors array contains plain language and display that in div.
        
        // For this example "form_error_message" will contain literal text no matter which error occurs.
        
        document.getElementById("form_error_message").innerHTML = "All fields are required.";
            
        // Notice we don't submit the form in this else block.
        // We need validation to submit the form when this function runs next time.
        
    }
        
    
}
```

```html
<!-- give all your input, select, and textarea fields IDs so they can be referenced via javascript -->
<!-- You can still give the "name" attributes if they are to be submitted. -->

<!-- give the form an ID. Remove any explicity "submit" button -->

<!-- Include real form line here to test -->
<!--form id="theForm" action="" method="" -->

<form id="theForm"> <!-- for testing here on SO -->
    A <input type id="a" name="a"><br/>
    B <input type id="b" name="b"><br/>
    <div id="form_error_message"></div>
    
</form>


<!-- Use type button on button ( and don't name oncick script submit(), important ) -->

<button type="button" onclick="validateFormOrSubmit()">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Wow , i'm getting it, i think the major problem was the adding of submit to the button. i have to take it off and do it in js codes

Comment: *"i have to take it off and do it in js codes"* ... yeah submit on native functionality is for test purposes these days. You have to find option for "Accepted Answer". So it gets a checkmark.

Comment: thank u , u made this simple, i hate jquery syntax so i was thinking it wouldnt be possible with it .....

Comment: No problem. I just didnt know you were serious at first.

Comment: oh lol, very serious, i started learning javascript 5 months now... but only problem was that everyone seems to be coding with frameworks like jquery , was hard finding someone who knows fully the javascript codes and i didnt like it. i want to move straight to react and angular after understanding more of JavaScript language.   it took me a week coding my own validation .....

Comment: I see. Yeah frameworks are popular. Serious hires want you to know vanilla too so stick to that track. But if (like for me) is all just learning, I'd suggest vanilla at first too, then (or same time) frameworks to see how you would make it simpler for yourself.

Comment: thank u once again, u r legend , i created an array and threw the letters in then called it. then I use for-loop to loop through . it worked miraculously... Thanks again once, i couldn't figure it out yesterday so slept , wake up , then i killed it simple

Answer (score 0):

you can change the action of the form in js under condition you want in JavaScript

```
if ( your statement ) {
document.getElementById("yourFormID").action="pageYouWant";

}
```